# How to add new auto-complete options in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: editors, texniccenter, auto-completion

When I type "ite" in TeXnicCenter, I see the autocomplete option:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
\end{itemize}
```

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> will activate the auto-completion. How do I add additional 
auto-completion options?

In particular, I would like "ali" to activate

```
\begin{align}

\end{align}
```

upon pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your TeXnicCenter installation folder and subfolders look out for `xml` files, such as `base.xml` and `math.xml`. Edit these files or create your own `xml` file.

Some example lines for `align` autocompletion:

```xml
<lxEnvironment name="align"
        parameters="1" 
        desc="Math environment"
        icon="math.bmp"
        index="10"
        expafter="}&#xA;&#x9;&amp; \\%&#xA;\end{align}" 
        expbefore="\begin{" />
```

Houston has posted instructions and a customized `xml` file here: [Missing autocompletition for \paragraph](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=11055). The `align` example is taken from that file.