# Snippet Manager in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I was wondering how do one find/use snippet manager for LaTeX code snippets in TeXnicCenter? I want to be able to define keyboard shortcuts such as for e.g.,

keystrokes: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> ⇒ `\[ <cursor> \]` and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> ⇒ `\( <cursor> \)`

Is this possible to implement? I am sure I will find other useful nitbit shortcut commands later on that will be useful for faster typing.

Comment: Someone may consider adding or changing the tag to something more descriptive if possible.

Comment: I don't use TeXnicCenter, so I can't really help you there. You could use something like [Auto-Hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to set that up to work regardless of what editor you are using though.

Comment: I think there is no real hotkey manager in texniccenter (at least not when I used it a while ago). The auto-completion functions are somewhere in the texniccenter folder in xml files. you might be able to add a function that lets you auto-complete the environments you want with Ctrl+Space. An externam hotkey tool might be easier...

Comment: With regards to xml files, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17240/how-to-add-new-auto-complete-options-in-texniccenter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org) allows you to add shortcuts to menu items only. Moreover, these shortcuts are required to be a "single-combined keypress event". Let me explain:

In your preference, the choice of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> is contained in          <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>. As such, you can assign the former to execute the menu sequence `Insert` -> `Formulas` -> `Formula`. This will insert `$<cursor>$`. Repeating this (by keeping <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed and just pressing <kbd>$</kbd> again), TeXnicCenter will insert a similar formula, which produces `$$<cursor>$$`.

This is how you do it in TeXnicCenter:

- `Tools` -> `Customize` -> `Keyboard`
- Under `Category`, choose `Insert`
- Under `Commands`, choose `Embedded Formula`
- In `Press New Shortcut Key`, while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>$</kbd>
- Press the `Assign` button

[image: Keyboard customization in TeXnicCenter]

Some caveats or considerations with regards to this technique: **Whenever** you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> you will receive `$<cursor>$`, even if you only want to type `\$` (say). Depending on your usage, this may be undesirable. Also, the use of `$$...$$` in LaTeX typesetting for displaymath has been succeeded by `\[...\]` (see the [`l2tabu` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)). You can set a separate keyboard shortcut for this (the menu item `Insert` -> `Formula` -> `Formula` produces
`\[<cursor>\]`.

To obtain exactly your preference (similar keystrokes to yield a choice between `\(<cursor>\)` and `\[<cursor>\]`) is not possible. You will have to produce completely separate keystroke combinations to obtain these different replacements. Note, however, that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> as well. So, for example, you could use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for `$<cursor>$`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> for `\[<cursor>\]`

With the above description, it should be straight-forward to do this.

Comment: +1... Werner: Thank You you so much for an elaborate response. This was very helpful. I like to actually be able to to understand and learn something from reading a response and yours did just that and summed it up in a less rigorous LaTeX explanation.

Comment: So when using the last option: `Ctrl+Alt+4` for `\(<cursor>\)` and the: `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+4` for `\[<cursor>\]`... I do not get the result as told. I just get `$<cursor>$`. Can I not get `\(<cursor>\)` and `\[<cursor>\]`?

Comment: @nightowl: I mistakenly put `\(<cursor>\)` in my final summary, as opposed an `Embedded formula` resembling `$<cursor>$`. I've corrected this in my updated answer. Not sure how fix this to print $\(<cursor>\)$. However, they are exactly the same in the typeset output.

Comment: Correct, I know they do the same job, but I read that `$...$` and `$$...$$` are both succeeded by `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` respectively. I do not know exactly why for `$...$` but I did hear that it was because of spacing issues related to using `$$...$$`. So is there a way to created a keyboard shortcut to produce `\[ <cursor> \]`?

Comment: Read the [`l2tabu` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) for more information on why `\[...\]` as opposed to `$$...$$`. Also, see [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764) My example above shows how to set `Embedded Formula`, which translates to `$<cursor>$`. You need to do the same for `Formula` if you want `\[<cursor>\]`.

Comment: I got it, is there a way to format how they display. I want both delimiters on one line instead of being on separate lines: ex. Line 1: `\[` and Line 2: `\]`